# Classloader issues loading library in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, jira

I am trying to write a new listener for Jira and I've encountered an issue that I would really appreciate some help and guidance with.

**Background**
We are running Jira 4.2.2 Enterprise WAR under Apache Tomcat. This includes the following jar files under webapps/jira/WEB-INF/lib:

```
* slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
* slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
```

We have a simple class that runs as a plugin. It receives events and based on the type of event, does some work. This class uses slf4j for logging and works as expected. The class is packaged into a jar and deployed under webapps/jira/WEB-INF/lib and used from there. We can add this as a listener, configure it and see init messages in the log. All logging happens through slf4j and works.

When we try and add functionality to our plugin from a 3rd party library, we receive the following exception:
com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

As slf4j is available and used by the class that we call this 3rd party library from, I do not understand what I am doing wrong or how to make this available at the time that the call is made.

**Working case**

In our code, we create a logger as follows:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.3rdparty.login;
public class JiraSampleListener extends AbstractIssueEventListener implements IssueEventListener {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JiraSampleListener.class);
    .
    .
    .
```

We can then use this by calling

```
logger.warn("MESSAGE")
```

The expected message appears in our logs.

**Error case**

As soon as we add the following code to this class, we receive the attached exception:

```
newThing = new 3rdPartyClass("name of thing");
```

**Exception**

> com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Any advice on resolving this or pointers to what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated!

A fuller view of the exception follows...

```
2011-01-19 05:30:51,016 main ERROR      [com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager] Error occurred 
while starting component 'com.atlassian.jira.event.DefaultListenerManager'.
com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:148)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:111)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference.get(ResettableLazyReference.java:89)
        at com.atlassian.jira.event.DefaultListenerManager$Listeners.start(DefaultListenerManager.java:93)
        at com.atlassian.jira.event.DefaultListenerManager.start(DefaultListenerManager.java:38)
        at com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager.quickStart(ComponentManager.java:256)
        at com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:212)
        at com.atlassian.jira.upgrade.ConsistencyLauncher.launchConsistencyChecker(ConsistencyLauncher.java:63)
        at com.atlassian.jira.upgrade.ConsistencyLauncher.contextInitialized(ConsistencyLauncher.java:42)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at 3rd.party.3rdPartyClassDefaultImpl.(3rdPartyClassDefaultImpl.java:101)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at 3rd.party.3rdParty.(3rdParty.java:107)
        at 3rd.party.3rdParty.(3rdParty.java:83)
        at 3rd.party.3rdParty.(3rdParty.java:67)
        at my.organisationlisteners.JiraSampleListener.init(JiraSampleListener.java:36)
        at com.atlassian.jira.event.ListenerFactory.getListener(ListenerFactory.java:33)
        at com.atlassian.jira.event.DefaultListenerManager$Listeners.loadListeners(DefaultListenerManager.java:126)
        at com.atlassian.jira.event.DefaultListenerManager$Listeners.create(DefaultListenerManager.java:71)
        at com.atlassian.jira.event.DefaultListenerManager$Listeners.create(DefaultListenerManager.java:66)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference$InternalReference.create(ResettableLazyReference.java:143)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$Sync.run(LazyReference.java:316)
        at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:142)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory at              
3rd.party.3rdPartyClassDefaultImpl.(3rdPartyClassDefaultImpl.java:101) at         
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) at 
3rd.party.3rdParty.(3rdParty.java:107) at 3rd.party.3rdParty.(3rdParty.java:83) at 
3rd.party.3rdParty.(3rdParty.java:67) at
```

It means that your class `3rdPartyClassDefaultImpl` cannot find `LoggerFactory`. Is this third party library located under CATALINA_HOME\lib ? if so it means that it's loaded by "Common classloader" ([classloaders in tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)) and all required classes (`3rdPartyClassDefaultImpl, LoggerFactory`) are searched in it's or parent's class repositories and cannot be found.

one of the posible solutions would be to place thirparty.jar under `web-inf/lib` or to move slf4j and log4jwrapper to `CATALINA_HOME\LIB`

Comment: The 3rd party library is on the classpath, defined under ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/setenv.sh

If I add slf4j to the classpath, then other application things no longer work.

Comment: It is the same class o problem as `CATALINA_HOME\lib`. If you cant move slf4j then try moving 3rd party lib to `web-inf\lib`